# Buffer in meters instead of degrees in south america

Tags: r, latitude-longitude, create, buffer

I need to create some buffer in meters, but it not possible how I'm doing. I really don't know what is happening.

My code:

```
library(rgdal)

minas_ti<- readOGR("minas_TI.shp")

minas_ti<-spTransform(minas_ti, CRSobj = "+proj=aea +lat_1=-2 +lat_2=-22 +lat_0=-12 +lon_0=-54 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=aust_SA +units=m +no_defs")
proj4string(minas_ti)

buff_min_ti10km<- gBuffer(minas_ti, width=10000, byid = T)
```

When I use the code above the buffer is generated in degrees.

Comment: Works okay for me using a spatial polygon of Brazil from raster::getData. What makes you think its in degrees? A 10,000 degree buffer would cover the whole world many times.

Comment: Exactly, when I plotted it generated a giant buffer. But when I used this code :buff_min_ti10km<- gBuffer(minas_ti, width=10, byid=TRUE)  generated a smaller buffer.
The weird thing I've used this code before, and it worked perfectly. I think it might be something related to Geographic Coordinate System.

Comment: I can only suggest that somehow you mistakenly buffered something that was still in lat-long. Or maybe the original shapefile projection wasn't set. Or something. Can you make a reproducible example with another data set? Or can you show some information about your data as its read from the shapefile? Print its bounding box and coordinate system string at each stage?